# SSRS report - calculated current printed position

Tags: reporting-services

Is SSRS (VS 2010), I have a problem on long report (many lines), since when there are two lines (line is a line of invoice, and may be with some remarks - the size of the line may vary.

I need also to calculate the current printed position, so I refer the current position, and break the page, and create a new one.
(I know also, which is the current line of the invoice before running the report).

How can I calculate the current position printed?
Can I know whether I am on the last page printed (that is intended to be printed)?

Also, can I force in tablix object that the total line (when doing grouping) will not be alone (will be at least with the last line of the tablix rows)?

Thanks :)

Comment: I love this question. Good luck!

Comment: What are you saying it doesn't make any sense ? Can you make it a bit clear with images or example ?

Comment: I have a textbox, i.e, the text box is located at specific position, but when I am using tablix and the text is after the tablix, the position may vary.
So I need to know the position, and refer it in my report (so I can know, whether I am in A4 to add a new page break or not, so I can control design of my report).